# How to preserve class in *ngFor while the array is updating?

Tags: angular

I have a simple list that needs to have one of its items selected on click. However, every x seconds the list "refreshes", and the selection seems to get lost.

To add the selection back to the newly created element, I introduced setTimeout, but that seems to have a "flashing" effect.

```
setInterval( () => {
  this.locations.forEach((o, i, a) => a[i] = a[i] + 's'); // update locations

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.selectedLocationID) document.getElementById(this.selectedLocationID).classList.add('selectedLocation');
  }, 0); 

}, 1000);
```

How to prevent the "flashing" as seen in the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sIbwcP0VapKhXq6tfPTZ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time this runs:

`this.locations.forEach((o, i, a) => a[i] = a[i] + 's'); // update locations`

the `*ngFor` completely re-draws the HTML from scratch, removing the class you added on the click:

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index;">
  <li id="location-{{i}}" (click)="selectLocation($event.target.id)">Hello {{location}}</li>
</div>
```

The trick is to ensure this class, if set, remains on the re-draw. Something like this (full solution here: https://plnkr.co/edit/6PTWU6dpQLSa5c3tVDbg):

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index;">
  <li id="location-{{i}}" (click)="selectLocation($event.target.id, i)" [ngClass]="{selectedLocation: selectedLocationIndex == i}">Hello {{location}}</li>
</div>
```

Rather than tracking the HTML element ID, my solution just tracks the index of the `*ngFor` loop, which we were already tracking with `let i = index` (passing `$event.target.id` is no longer required, but won't hurt anything).

We then use `[ngClass]` to set/remove the 'selectedLocation' class if the index of our loop, `i`, matches the index of the selected item that we are now tracking with `selectedLocationIndex`.

Comment: Right. And, generally speaking, do not manipulate DOM directly unless necessary. I.e. `document.getElementById(locationID).classList.add('selectedLocation')`  is really really bad. `[ngClass]` is the way to go.

Comment: Much cleaner. Thank you. I was under the impression that I could use [ngClass] and [class.selectedLocation] interchangably, and the latter gave an "expression has changed since the beginning" error.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go buddy**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h3> Select an item </h3>
<div *ngFor="let location of locations; let i=index;">
<div [ngClass]="{'selectedLocation':selectedLocation==i}">
  <li (click)="selectLocation(i)">Hello {{location}}</li>
</div>
</div>
`
})
export class App {
selectedLocation;
locations: Array = ["World", "Mars", "Saturn", "Pluto"];

constructor() {
// datasource updates every sec
setInterval( () => {
  this.locations.forEach((o, i, a) => a[i] = a[i] + 's'); // update locations

  // if (this.selectedLocationID) document.getElementById(this.selectedLocationID).classList.add('selectedLocation');

  setTimeout(() => {
    //if (this.selectedLocationID) document.getElementById(this.selectedLocationID).classList.add('selectedLocation');
  }, 0); 

}, 1000);
}

selectLocation(i) {
this.selectedLocation = i;
}
}

@NgModule({
 imports: [ BrowserModule ],
 declarations: [ App ],
 bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```